# Проверка на монотонную последовательность(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Программа получает список чисел. Требуется определить, является ли список монотонной последовательностью (невозрастающей или неубывающей). Вывести Yes или No.
>
> Входные данные:
> `-96 -96 -85 -82 -76 -64 -56 -47 -44 -44 -13 16 20 40 55 59 79 82 100 100`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что первые четыре теста проходят, а последний нет, думаю дело в двух строках, то есть приходит в input сразу две списка, и поиск сбивается:

```
-83 -6 42 70 -22 -48 -20 -86 -9 -34 -45 -74 -61 -66
-2 -25 65 -96
```

Вот код:

```
a = input()

def parse(lst):
    def sort(x):
        return sorted(x)

    number = list(filter(lambda x: type(x) == int, lst))
    if number == sort(number):
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')


parse(a)
```

Помогите)

Comment: а у тебя точно `numer` не пустой? Дело в том, что `a` введено с клавиатуры, значит это строка. `filter` пройдётся по каждому элементу строки, то есть по каждому символу. У символа тип не может быть равен `int`, поэтому `number` окажется пустым

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему бы вам не использовать `split` для разбиения строки на числа?
Кроме того, вы проверяете только один порядок сортировки списка, но не проверяете обратный ему

```py
def parse(lst):
    def sort(x):
        return sorted(x)

    number = [int(c) for c in a.split()]
    if number == sort(number) \
    or number == list(reversed(sort(number))):
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```